# Appcelerator Titanium Internationalization not working right

Tags: android, iphone, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

Here's one that's driving me crazy:

I have recently started looking into Appcelerator Titanium. I have built a few small apps both with a normal project and using Alloy so I understand the basics at least.

One thing I just cannot get working is the i18n folder/files.

Here is what ive done:
- Create a "Default Project"
- add folder to root directory "i18n"
- add "en" and "es" folder to "i18n"
- add "strings.xml" to both those new folders.
- added:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <resources>
       <string name="welcome_message">Welcome TEST</string>
    </resources>
```

to both the strings.xml, except in the es strings I put "ES Welcome TEST".
- In Resources -> app.js I changed "I am Window 1" to L('welcome_message')
- Ran the application

Both the normal and alloy versions just show a blank screen. I would like to get my alloy app working the most but from what I understand the localization code should work the same in both apps. In alloy I may just have to put it in the style.

Any pointers would be great! I have looked at other post claiming its not working but all of them were either syntax errors or just set it up wrong. I have copied their code and have the exact same issue with it not working so I have a feeling im missing a newbie step.

-- Here are some screenshots, I just created a brand new regular(not alloy) project, added the code above and try to use L('welcome_message') to no luck. I tried installing everything on a new PC to make sure I wasn't messing anything up on my main computer.
[image]
[image]

Comment: did you try clean and build?

Comment: I have tried that as well as tried creating a blank project like mentioned above, adding the code, then running it for the first time and same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres the answer:

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Internationalization

Ends up by default your manifest file is not setup by default to allow localization UNLESS you choose a tabbed project.

Kinda silly if you ask me.

Comment: It won't work, even after going through the guide. I have created i18n folder and also strings.xml and have declared L('password') it leaves the UI empty on the simulator for the translation.

Answer (score 0):

For the topic poster:

My new string.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="welcome_message">Don't Help Austin</string>
    <string name="user_agent_message">user agent set to</string>
    <string name="format_test">Your name is %s</string>
    <string name="base_ui_title">Base UI</string>
    <string name="controls_win_title">Controls</string>
    <string name="phone_win_title">Phone</string>
    <string name="platform_win_title">Platform</string>
    <string name="mashups_win_title">Mashups</string>
    <string name="ordered">Hi %1$s, my name is %2$s</string>
</resources>
```

Screenshot of my non-Alloy experiment:

[image]

**For those looking to answer the question in the topic, this is a possible answer below.**

My i18n folder is on the same hierarchy level as app and plugins, so mine isn't inside the app folder like the rest of the Alloy resources.

index.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <Label id="label" onClick="doClick"></Label>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

index.tss

```
".container": {
    backgroundColor:"white"
},
"Label": {
    width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    color: "#000",
    text: L("welcome_message")
}
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="welcome_message">Welcome to Kitchen Sink for Titanium</string>
    <string name="user_agent_message">user agent set to</string>
    <string name="format_test">Your name is %s</string>
    <string name="base_ui_title">Base UI</string>
    <string name="controls_win_title">Controls</string>
    <string name="phone_win_title">Phone</string>
    <string name="platform_win_title">Platform</string>
    <string name="mashups_win_title">Mashups</string>
    <string name="ordered">Hi %1$s, my name is %2$s</string>
</resources>
```

When I placed the L("welcome_message") inside the index.xml, it didn't work.

Comment: I do like your sense of humor :) but the answer you post doesnt help me with my specific problem. What youve posted is from many of the guides out there, I can load projects straight from github, run them and they dont work either. Thats what ive been trying tonight. Is there a setting within eclipse I need to set or maybe in the emulator manager?

Comment: @Martin you said "When I placed the L("welcome_message") inside the index.xml, it didn't work." Is this the question or answer? Because I also need the solution for it in alloy project as it is not working

Comment: Did you do the steps the original poster detailed? "Here is what ive done: - Create a "Default Project" - add folder to root directory "i18n" - add "en" and "es" folder to "i18n" - add "strings.xml" to both those new folders"